# Evaluating use of INDIRECT function taken from Cell Validation

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of cells which have validation lists that are based on the use of the INDIRECT function. In this case there are two variables - one is the currently selected State (as reference through the named range dtState) and another based on a separate selection already made by the user in a different cell. The function in the Validation List for the cell is:

=INDIRECT("dtHdrPlates"&dtSize&dtState)

- dtsize : could equal "70" or "90"
- dtState : couldequal "VIC" or "QLD"

Naturally there is a named range for all combination of "dtHdrPlates" and the possible options of dtSize and dtState. The INDIRECT function in the Cell Validation list gives me a list that changes based on the selections in other cells.

- dtHdrPlates70VIC
- dtHdrPlates90VIC
- dtHrdPlates70QLD
- dthrdPlates90QLD

This works well thanks to advice previously obtained in this forum - thanks!

---

I am now trying to implement the use of a Combo Box over top of this cell, positioned, populated, made visible, activated and if relevant, dropped down by VBA Code; and removed once the use leaves the control.

Where I'm currently stuck is populating the **ListFillRange** of the ComboBox in the sheet - based on the  INDIRECT function in the **Validation.Formula1** of the cell the combo box is intended to supplant.

```
Sub BuildComboBox(rngCell as Range)
' This procedure checks to see if the Cell concerned is a list, and if so creates a combobox over top of the cell with the appropriate contents.

Dim rngCell as Range ' the cell concerned
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim Dim cbo As OLEObject

If rngCell.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then

    Set ws = Excel.ActiveSheet
    Set cbo = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ComboBox")

    cbo.Left = rngCell.Left
    cbo.Top = rngCell.Top
    cbo.Width = rngCell.Width
    cbo.Height = rngCell.Height
    CBO.LISTFILLRANGE = RNGCELL.VALIDATION.FORMULA1
    cbo.LinkedCell = rngCell.Address

    If rngCell.Validation.ShowError = True Then
        CBO.MATCHREQUIRED = TRUE
    Else
        CBO.MATCHREQUIRED = FALSE
    End If

    cbo.Visible = True
    cbo.Activate
    If rngCell.Value2 = "" Then
        CBO.DROPDOWN
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

I am stuck in three places in the above code (where the code is in CAPITALS).

What I would like to solve at the moment is how to get the indirect function taken from the cell validation list (**rngCell.Validation.Formula1**) and have it converted to the named range acceptable to **cbo.ListFillRange** - at the moment it comes across as **=INDIRECT("dtHdrPlates"&sglLBWWallThickness&dtState)** which does not work.

I've been playing with the EVALUATE function but just can't get it to parse the text coming from the Validation.formula1

If while you're looking at this you could also steer me towards how to change the status of an ActiveX ComboBox's MatchRequire property - and how to force it to DropDown, that would be lovely too.

Thanks, Regards, Ken

Comment: Out of interest why are you trying this approach if you have working DV?

Comment: In VBA you don't need INDIRECT, you can just reference the range, viz `Range("dtHdrPlates" & dtSize & dtState)`.

Comment: SJR - because of the nature of the data entry process and the information going into the cells - being able to commence typing into the cell and have the selection autocomplete based on entries in the list would be a tremendous boon to data entry for this application.

Comment: SJR - The Indirect statement is different in each different cell. So I can't (don't want to!) hard code the indirect statement into VBA for the 30 or so cells this technique would currently be applicable to. I need to leave the code as robust to changes in the sheet as possible. What I need the code to to is take the statement =INDIRECT("dtHdrPlates"&sglLBWWallThickness&dtState) and on the fly resolve it down to the named range (or resulting address range) for the Combo Box - given that the construction inside the Indirect () can change significantly between cells.

Comment: SJR - thanks for reading and commenting!

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding but if `dtState` is a named range then `range(range("dtState"))` will give you the range contained in that named range. Does that move you in the right direction? A screenshot might help (simplified probably).

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. In essence the value in the "Source:" control of the Data Validation dialog box is an indirect statement  (=INDIRECT("dtHdrPlates"&sglLBWWallThickness&dtState) - ignoring what is actually inside the brackets - because this changes from cell to cell - I need to do what the Indirect Function does and translate that text string ("dtHdrPlates"&sglLBWWallThickness&dtState) into a Named Range. But I there doesn't seem to be an equivalent to INDIRECT in VBA?

Comment: As my example above was supposed to show, you don't need INDIRECT in VBA, you can use a range as an "argument" to range. If you have the text "A1" in cell B1 and 10 in cell A1 then `range(range("B1"))` will return 10.